# How to optimize this PHP script / remove HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, optimization

I don't want to repeat all the HTML stuff in the second `echo`. Basically, for every PHP output I'm working with I have to add the style sheet etc. (all the HTML stuff). An idea from me would be to use HTML which gets an answer from the PHP like LoginFailed and then just displays a whole and well designed HTML but how should you do that?

```
if($user->data['user_id'] != ANONYMOUS)
    {
       // Do something if logged in
    }
else
    {
        echo '
        <head>
        <title>You are not logged in</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/form.css">
        </head> 
        <font face="Arial" size="6" color="white">Please make sure that you are logged in <p> <a href="Login.php">Go to the login page</a></font> ';
        exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put the repeated code in an external file an use [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) to load it at the top of every PHP?

Comment: Included link to `require` documentation, but the markup masks the link color :)

Answer (score 1):

Put `require_once ("your_header.php");` and put it at the top of all your pages! Rather than coding it in to ever PHP page. It saves a lot of space in PHP code and if you edit it once, then it changes across all you PHP pages.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't select both of your answer but thank you too!